# Gradle build failed on a new local environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently switched PCs so I had to set my local environment from scratch.

After pulling the project and prepping all the other stuff, I cant seem to get it to run.

On the `build` tab in Intellij, I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationInvocationException'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

I'm suspecting this is related to gradle but my initial google search got me nowhere. There shouldn't be anything wrong with the project since I can run it fine on a separate machine so this is an issue with my local environment. The rest of the project is built using java spring boot, if that helps. Any help here?

Comment: Goto File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools  : Check whether everything is correctly set up

Comment: IntelliJ- did you try invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: You could try it on terminal. The uncertainty would be less.